# the referrer relay response or receipt link url is invalid

Tags: php, authorize.net

After transaction got successful at authorize.net SIM method it is not redirecting to my website URL. I am getting the error message

> the referrer relay response or receipt link url is invalid

Here is my code of my transaction page which is submitting information. Please let me know my mistake in it.

```
<!-- Create the HTML form containing necessary SIM post values -->
 <form method="post" id="finalform" action="<?php echo $url; ?>" >
  <!--  Additional fields can be added here as outlined in the SIM integration guide  
  at:  http://developer.authorize.net -->
   <input type='hidden' name='x_login'                 value='<?php echo $loginID; ?>' />
   <input type='hidden' name='x_amount'  onkeyup="gethash(this.value);"      value='<?php echo $amount; ?>' /><br/>
   <input type='hidden' name='x_description'           value='<?php echo $description; ?>' />
   <input type='hidden' name='x_invoice_num'           value='<?php echo $invoice; ?>' /><br/>
   <input type='hidden' name='x_fp_sequence'           value='<?php echo $sequence; ?>' />
   <input type='hidden' name='x_fp_timestamp'          value='<?php echo $timeStamp; ?>' />
   <input type='hidden' name='x_fp_hash'  id="fphash"  value='<?php echo $fingerprint; ?>' />
   <input type='hidden' name='x_test_request'          value='<?php echo $testMode; ?>' />
   <input type='hidden' name="x_first_name"            value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['fne'];?>" />
   <input type='hidden' name="x_last_name"             value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['lne'];?>" />
   <input type='hidden' name="x_company"               value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['orgme'];?>" />
   <input type='hidden' name="x_address"               value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['adds'];?>" />
   <input type='hidden' name="x_city"                  value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['cty'];?>" />
   <input type='hidden' name="x_state"                 value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['ste'];?>" />
   <input type='hidden' name="x_zip"                   value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['zip'];?>" />
   <input type='hidden' name="x_cust_id"               value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['cusd'];?>" />
   <input type="hidden" name="x_receipt_link_method"   value="LINK" >
   <input type="hidden" name="x_receipt_link_url"      value="http://www.uthstuph.com/payment-success/" >
   <input type="hidden" name="x_relay_response"        value="TRUE" >
   <input type="hidden" name="x_relay_url"             value="http://www.uthstuph.com/payment-success" >
   <input type="hidden" name="x_phone"                value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['phone'];?>"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="x_email"                value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['email'];?>"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="x_billing_zip" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['x_billing_zip'];?>"/>
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['cno'];?>" autocomplete="off" maxlength="16" name="x_card_num" id="x_card_num" class="input_text"><br/>
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['cexp'];?>" autocomplete="off" maxlength="20" name="x_exp_date" id="x_exp_date" class="input_text">
   <input type="hidden"  name="x_card_code" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['ccode'];?>"/>
 </form>


<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("finalform").submit();
</script>
```

IN ACCOUNT SETTING I set
Default Receipt URL : http://www.uthstuph.com/payment-success/

Default Relay Response URL : http://www.uthstuph.com/payment-success/

I have tried both http as well as https.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Authorize.net support](https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A601) page:

> Error 14 may also occur if you try to submit `x_receipt_link_url` and
>   `x_relay_url` simultaneously, instead of choosing a receipt method.

Remove one of them and they should work. Also, from your Authorize.net account try the following:

To add a valid Response/Receipt URL:

> 1. Log into the Merchant Interface at https://account.authorize.net.
> 2. Click Account from the main toolbar.
> 3. Click Response/Receipt URLs under
> 4. Transaction Format Settings.
> 5. Click Add URL.
> 6. Enter your Response URL.
> 7. Click Submit